# How to prevent For loop from producing duplicates of the same result of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have two arrays, one is a list of names, and one is a list of age that is generated with a function. To make things easier, i'll just show the final result of the two arrays.

```
let nameList=["John","Brenda","Sabrina","Ray","Jacob"];
let ageList=[ 23, 29, 30, 23, 25 ]
```

I wanted to create a new array where i can combine each name paired with the age number of the same sequence. Ex: John will have 23 next to it, Brenda 29, Sabrina 30, and so on.

I have written this function to do it

```
function combineData (nameArray,ageArray,combArray){
    let tempComb=[];
    for (let i=0;i<nameArray.length;i++) {
        tempComb.push(nameArray[i]);
        tempComb.push(ageArray[i]);
        combArray.push(tempComb);
    }
}
```

The result of this loop kinda did what i wanted to get, but not really. Below is the result it returns

```
[ [ 'John', 23, 'Brenda', 29, 'Sabrina', 30, 'Ray', 23, 'Jacob', 25 ],
  [ 'John', 23, 'Brenda', 29, 'Sabrina', 30, 'Ray', 23, 'Jacob', 25 ],
  [ 'John', 23, 'Brenda', 29, 'Sabrina', 30, 'Ray', 23, 'Jacob', 25 ],
  [ 'John', 23, 'Brenda', 29, 'Sabrina', 30, 'Ray', 23, 'Jacob', 25 ],
  [ 'John', 23, 'Brenda', 29, 'Sabrina', 30, 'Ray', 23, 'Jacob', 25 ] ]
```

can anybody tell me how to prevent it from duplicating?

Extra question. Is there a way to put each name & age pairing into their own array and then combine it with the others which will create a nested array like this?

`[['John', 23],['Brenda',29],['Sabrina',30],['Ray',23],['Jacob',25]]`

Comment: I forgot to add that i added a third variable of `let combList=[];`

Comment: And this is the final function being called `combineData(nameList,ageList,combList);`

Comment: Declare temp inside the loop so it becomes independent

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik holy crap this is it..thanks a lot! Okay, so i'm fairly new to javascript and i'm trying to understand why i need to put it inside. Is it because so that the temp will be empty again before i `push` it into the `combArray` after the previous iteration?

Comment: Javascript looks like its made of pointers to objects so each time you add actually adds pointer to same object. But in a loop it re-creates new object and they are different pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the names and use the index to add the element from the ages array.

```js
const nameList = [ 'John', 'Brenda', 'Sabrina', 'Ray', 'Jacob' ];
const ageList = [ 23, 29, 30, 23, 25 ];

const out = nameList.map((name, i) => {
  return [name, ageList[i]];
});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a one liner in various underscore like libraries. The function usually called zip.

```
const results = _.zip(nameList, ageList)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const nameList = ["John", "Brenda", "Sabrina", "Ray", "Jacob"];
const ageList = [23, 29, 30, 23, 25];

function zipper(arr1, arr2) {
  const temp = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    temp[arr1[i]] = arr2[i];
  }
  return Object.entries(temp);
}
```